# Custom resource outputs not found

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I've written a custom resource in Go using `cloudformation-cli-go-plugin`, it's failing when I try and use it in a stack with

```
Unable to retrieve Guid attribute for MyCo::CloudFormation::Workloads, with error message NotFound guid not found.
```

The stack:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Sample MyCo Workloads Template
Resources:
  Resource1:
    Type: 'MyCo::CloudFormation::Workloads'
    Properties:
      APIKey: ""
      AccountID: ""
      Workload: >-
        workload: {entityGuids: "", name: "CloudFormationTest-Create"}
Outputs:
  CustomResourceAttribute1:
    Value: !GetAtt  Resource1.Guid
```

If I remove the `Outputs` stanza the stack runs successfully and I can see the created resource.

Running with SAM locally I've verified that `Guid` is in fact always returned. FWIW the resource passes all of the contract tests, `Guid` is the `primaryIdentifier`, and is a `readOnlyProperties`.

I've tried several tests playing with the `!GetAtt` definition, all of which fail with schema errors so it appears the CF is aware of the format of the resource's properties.

Suggestions and/or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is Read failing due to CloudFormation behaving differently than the Contract Tests. The Contract Tests do not follow the CloudFormation model rules, they are more permissive.

There are a number of differences in how the Contract Tests and CloudFormation behave- passing the Contract Tests does not guarantee CloudFormation compatibility. Two for instances:

- The contract tests allow returning a temporary `primaryIdentifier` that can change between `handler.InProgress` and `handler.Success`
- The contract tests pass the *entire* model to all events. CloudFormation only passes the `primaryIdentifier` to `Read` and `Delete`.